# React: Persisting State Using Local Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state

I am coding an app in which there is a collection of reviews and a person can respond to a review, but each review can only have one response. So far, I am doing this by rendering a ReviewResponseBox component in my ReviewCardDetails component and passing the review_id as props.
I have implemented the logic so that once there is one ReviewResponse, the form to write another will no longer appear. However, before I was initializing the state in this component with an empty array, so when I refreshed my page the response went away and the form came back up. (This is now commented out)

I am trying to resolve this by persisting my state using React LocalStorage but am having trouble writing my method to do this. Here is what I have so far:

Component that renders ReviewResponseBox and passes review_id as props:

```
import React from "react";
import './Review.css';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import StarRatings from "react-star-ratings";
import ReviewResponseBox from "../ReviewResponse/ReviewResponseBox";

const ReviewCardDetails = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { review } = location?.state; // ? - optional chaining

  console.log("history location details: ", location);
  return (
    <div key={review.id} className="card-deck">
      <div className="card">
        <div>
        <div className='card-container'>
          <h4 className="card-title">{review.place}</h4>
          <StarRatings
            rating={review.rating}
            starRatedColor="gold"
            starDimension="20px"
          />
          <div className="card-body">{review.content}</div>
          <div className="card-footer">
            {review.author} - {review.published_at}
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br></br>
    <ReviewResponseBox review_id={review.id}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReviewCardDetails;
```

component that I want to keep track of the state so that it can render the form or response:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReviewResponse from './ReviewResponse';
import ReviewResponseForm from './ReviewResponseForm';
import { reactLocalStorage } from "reactjs-localstorage";

class ReviewResponseBox extends React.Component {
 // constructor() {
  //  super()

 //   this.state = {
  //    reviewResponses: []
  //  };
//  }

 fetchResponses = () => {
  let reviewResponses = [];
  localStorage.setResponses
  reviewResponses.push(reviewResponse);
}
  
  render () {
    const reviewResponses = this.getResponses();
    const reviewResponseNodes = <div className="reviewResponse-list">{reviewResponses}</div>;
   
    return(
      <div className="reviewResponse-box">
        {reviewResponses.length 
          ? (
            <>
              {reviewResponseNodes}
            </>
          )
          : (
            <ReviewResponseForm addResponse={this.addResponse.bind(this)}/>
          )}
      </div> 
        
    );
  } 
  

  addResponse(review_id, author, body) {
    const reviewResponse = {
      review_id,
      author,
      body
    };
    this.setState({ reviewResponses: this.state.reviewResponses.concat([reviewResponse]) }); // *new array references help React stay fast, so concat works better than push here.
  }
   
  
  
  getResponses() {    
    return this.state.reviewResponses.map((reviewResponse) => { 
      return (
        <ReviewResponse 
          author={reviewResponse.author} 
          body={reviewResponse.body} 
          review_id={this.state.review_id} />
      ); 
    });
  }

  
  
}
export default ReviewResponseBox;
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would persist the responses to localStorage when they are updated in state using the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. Use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to read in the localStorage value and set the local component state, or since reading from localStorage is synchronous directly set the initial state.

I don't think you need a separate package to handle this either, you can use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) easily.

```
import React from "react";
import ReviewResponse from "./ReviewResponse";
import ReviewResponseForm from "./ReviewResponseForm";

class ReviewResponseBox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    reviewResponses: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`reviewResponses-${this.props.review_id}`)) || []
  };

  storageKey = () => `reviewResponses-${this.props.review_id}`;

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.reviewResponses !== this.state.reviewResponses) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        `reviewResponses-${this.props.review_id}`,
        JSON.stringify(this.state.reviewResponses)
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const reviewResponses = this.getResponses();
    const reviewResponseNodes = (
      <div className="reviewResponse-list">{reviewResponses}</div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="reviewResponse-box">
        {reviewResponses.length ? (
          <>{reviewResponseNodes}</>
        ) : (
          <ReviewResponseForm addResponse={this.addResponse.bind(this)} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  addResponse(review_id, author, body) {
    const reviewResponse = {
      review_id,
      author,
      body
    };
    this.setState({
      reviewResponses: this.state.reviewResponses.concat([reviewResponse])
    }); // *new array references help React stay fast, so concat works better than push here.
  }

  getResponses() {
    return this.state.reviewResponses.map((reviewResponse) => {
      return (
        <ReviewResponse
          author={reviewResponse.author}
          body={reviewResponse.body}
          review_id={this.state.review_id}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Drew. This helps a ton. The problem is, now when I comment on one review, that comment is showing up on all the reviews. I thought that passing in the review_id as props would remedy this but it does not seem it has...

Comment: @bab For sure... I was trying to figure out if this was the case or not... and if so, then you can either use a computed key for the storage, or nest all the state in a single key and then use the review id to access/update a specific sub state. The former is easier, i.e. ```.setItem(`reviewResponses-${id}`, JSON.stringify(.....))``` and ```.getItem(`reviewResponses-${id}`)```.

Comment: hey drew, thanks for this. I implemented that, but am now getting errors saying "id is not defined"

Comment: is this what you meant? `state = {
    reviewResponses: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`reviewResponses-${id}`)) || []
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.reviewResponses !== this.state.reviewResponses) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        `reviewResponses-${id}`,
        JSON.stringify(this.state.reviewResponses)
      );
    }
  }`

Comment: Yes, but you need to either define `id` locally, or get the current value from the reviews being reviewed. Oh, I see, looks like it's passed as a prop, so use `this.props.review_id` when computing the storage key.